# Is there a Python function or way to perform cross validation on a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract x amount of elements from a list and create a new list. Then restore the extracted elements, and extract the adjacent x amount of elements until every set (of size x) of elements has been extracted once.

I’d need to create a for loop that:

1. extracts x amount of elements each run
2. creates a new list without those elements
3. Performs an action
4. Restores those elements and extracts the next x elements after that until a list has been created the last x amount of elements have extracted.

**Example**

**List**: A B C D E F G H I J

**amount_elements_to_extract**: 2

Original List: A B C D E F G H I J

Run 1

New list: C D E F G H I J

Extracted: A B

Run 2

New list: A B E F G H I J

Extracted: C D

Run 3

New list: A B C D E F I J

Extracted: E F

Run 4

New list: A B C D E F G H

Extracted: G H

**What’s the most efficient way, or which library should I use to program this in python?**

Here is the dictionary I'm working with (I'm trying to perform this on the elements housing the two elements input and key):

```
list =  [
                {
                 'input':['/82161/pets/food',
                          '/82161/mister/yellow',
                          '/82161/mister/green',
                          '/82161/mister/blue'],
                 'key': '/82161/pets/full'
                },
                {
                 'input':['/62314/pets/food',
                          '/62314/mister/yellow',
                          '/62314/mister/green',
                          '/62314/mister/blue'],
                 'key': '/62314/pets/full'
                },
                {
                 'input':['/33209/pets/food',
                          '/33209/mister/yellow',
                          '/33209/mister/green',
                          '/33209/mister/blue'],
                 'key':'/33209/pets/full'
                },
                {
                 'input':['/35602/pets/food',
                          '/35602/mister/yellow',
                          '/35602/mister/green',
                          '/35602/mister/blue'],
                 'key': '/35602/pets/full'
                }
                ]
```

Here is my attempt:

```
original_test_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
test_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

original_amount = 3
amount = original_amount
base = 0

print("this is the length of the list " + str(len(test_list)))
while ( amount <= len(test_list)):
    for x in range(base, amount):
        print("this is x " + str(x))

    if (amount+original_amount >= len(test_list)):
        amount += len(test_list) % original_amount
        base += len(test_list) % original_amount
    else:
        amount += original_amount
        base += original_amount

    print("amount " + str(amount))
    print("base " + str(base))
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Do you mean like cross validation for model validation? So, in your examples above, training-set == C D E F G H I J and test-set == A B ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes

Comment: So, questions seeking out library recommendations are considered off-topic, although, you have provided your attempt. So this might not be received well. But generally for Python, one standard library for machine learning is [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/). It is a batteries-included library for predictive data analysis, one major portion of it is for [model selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_selection.html#model-selection), which includes various useful api's for [cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

Comment: @deadshot Sorry for not being clear. I'm trying to extract x amount of elements from a list and create a new list. Then restore the extracted elements, and extract the adjacent x amount of elements until every set (of size x) of elements has been extracted once.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was hoping to not have to use an external ML library but a Python library function for lists or dictionaries etc or an algorithm. Is there an algorithm or function for manipulating lists I've described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's a very basic approach to split up the data into training and testing sets based on the size of the test set (note, usually this is done in terms of the *number of folds*).

```
data = list("ABCDEFGHIJ")

n = 2

for start in range(0, len(data), n):
    stop = start + n
    test = data[start: stop]
    train = data[:start] + data[stop:]
    print(test, train)
```

The output here would be:

```
['A', 'B'] ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
['C', 'D'] ['A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
['E', 'F'] ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
['G', 'H'] ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'I', 'J']
['I', 'J'] ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```